# Compile and Runtime problems with dictionary setting MSoft Scripting Runtime flg for portability?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm experimenting with different ways to do Dictionaries in VBA along with setting the Microsoft Scripting Runtime from code for portability so that the next person's computer doesn't have to turn this VBA tools checkbox on.

Q1:The first issue is setting the MSoft Scripting Runtime flag on in VBA code which should be done at the beginning. I'm not sure if the Msoft Script Control 1.0 is needed for anything or when it is actually needed? Thus during runtime the commented out "Set Refearly..." statement errors out with
"Name conflicts with existing module, project or object library". I'm not sure if it's the filename or the variable that's the issue?  Moreover, if I uncheck the flag for this in tools, then it won't compile since it doesn't know what to do with scripting. dictionary. Also once the Reference object is set, what is needed to actually toggle the flag on from VBA in the VBE tools dialog box?

Q2:The second issue is method 1 where I get a compile-time error of "invalid use of new keyword" even though the MSoft Scripting Runtime and ...Extension in tools is checked.  I've entered what various sites show to be the correct way to get this to work and it isn't working... What is wrong here?

Q3: Is it confusing it with Office Words definition of Dictionary? If not, then I may add a fourth method to define a custom Word dictionary for names where the definition for each name entered is whether they are an employee or manager, etc.

The other methods 2 and 3 will compile and work. So any code past this point can be the same code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Dictionary_Test()


' Set the "Microsoft scripting Runtime" library for portability. Needs to be done first.
    ' Unknown if "Microsoft Script Control 1.0" library needs to be checked in tools
    ' Could set the "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3" same way
    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.references.addfromfile
    ' References!referencename
    
    Dim Refearly As Reference  ' doesn't use the reference events functionality.
    'Set Refearly = ActiveDocument.VBProject.References.AddFromFile("C:\windows\system32\scrrun.dll")  'Early Binding
     
     'If Refearly.BuiltIn Then
     '  Debug.Print "Found Microsoft Scripting Runtime "
    'End If

'//======== Collection: Method 0 ======'
Dim varc As Collection    ' Method 0
    Set varc = New Collection
    
     varc.Add "John"
     varc.Add "Star"
     
     Debug.Print " Method 0: using Collection " & varc.Item(1) & Space(2) & varc.Item(2)
   
'//======== Dictionary: Method 1========='
Dim dict As Dictionary  ' method 1
Dim dicts As Dictionaries

' Get compiletime error of "invalid use of new keyword"
    'Set dict = New Dictionary
      
    'dict.Add "First Name", "John"
    'dict.Add "Last Name", "Star"

    'Debug.Print " Method 1: using Dictionary " vbTab & dict.Items()(0), dict.Items()(1)
    
'//======== Dictionary: Method 2========='
    Dim odict As Object ' method 2
    Set odict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")  ' method 2 late binding
    odict.Add "First Name", "John"
    odict.Add Key:="Last Name", Item:="Star"
    
    Debug.Print " Method 2: using object Scripting Dictionary " & odict.Items()(0), odict.Items()(1)
    
'//===== Dictionary: Method 3==========='
    Dim sdict As Scripting.Dictionary   ' method 3
    Set sdict = New Scripting.Dictionary ' method 3
  
    sdict.Add "First Name", "John"
    sdict.Add Key:="Last Name", Item:="Star"
  
    Debug.Print " Method 3: Scripting Dictionary " & sdict.Items()(0), sdict.Items()(1)
    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 doesn't work because you have failed to specify the library when declaring the variables. As Word also has a `Dictionaries` collection of `Dictionary` objects it assumes that is what the declaration refers to. Your Method 3 is the correct way of declaring variables from the `Scripting` library.

If you are saving your code in a template that you intend to distribute the References are saved with the code project so there is no need for any other user 'to turn this VBA tools checkbox on'.